# Oracle : Indexing JSON type column in ORACLE, targeted JSON field may be absent from the data queried

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, indexing

I am trying to set up an index on a column in ORACLE that has JSON type data. The field on which I am setting up data, is present in some records and is not present in other, basically that field is optional .

I already have code in hibernate that queries a list of ids, I want to index this on the database so that the search is efficient.

I tried **json_textcontains**, unfortunately it only works on single value it does not work on list, I used *section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)* strategy to create index.

I tried setting up index on JSON_VALUE with *ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY* as recommended by Oracle, it still dosent show me expected values when I do EXPLAIN PLAN on the search.

```
CREATE INDEX PARAM_ADDRESS_ID_INDX ON EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION(
  JSON_VALUE(PARAMETERS, '$.addressId' RETURNING VARCHAR2(4000) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
);
```

The json inside PARAMETERS column looks as shown below:-

```
{"type":"home","addressId":128,"description":"This is test address 1"}
{"type":"away","referenceId":3341,"description":"Test away description"}
{"type":"away","addressId":129,"description":"This is test address 2"}
```

As you can see in first record *addressId* is present in the second one its not and third one its present. So from my code when I do an IN using JPA hibernate I just provide addressIds that have values 128,129.

I expect when I query I should see INDEX information in the EXPLAIN PLAN but instead I see below:-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                     |   154 |   109K| 11864   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION|   154 |   109K| 11864   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks a lot for reading so far, appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ORACLE OPTIMIZER will always choose FULL TABLE SCAN on table with 154 rows. There are too few entries for choosing index. But, if you want to use the created index, you have to ask that with optimizer hints:

```
SELECT  /*+ INDEX(a PARAM_ADDRESS_ID_INDX)*/ *
FROM EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION a
WHERE ......
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So does that mean once I have more records it will start using the index? I tried as you mentioned and I got response back.

Answer (score 0):

I came across http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01450_maximum_key_length_exceeded.htm while creating INDEX with higher value for VARCHAR2, it mentions -

> As a general rule, indexing on very large columns (raw, long, clob) is
>   rarely useful because the optimizer will almost always find a
>   full-table scan cheaper than invoking an index on a long column value.

Since the CLOB data is JSON, I think its not a good idea to return VARCHAR2(4000) as the schema for JSON is not fixed in this case. Hence for this use case its not ideal to create index and return fixed length VARCHAR2 as part of it.